# How to remove any role by using removeRole() in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have three models user,roles,model_has_roles,when i assign any role to the user from the roles table it's creating an instance of the model in `model_has_roles` table.I am using `removeRole()` laravel method for removing roles ,i am giving some details what are the roles present inside my database like(super-market,notification,all...).it's deleteing all roles except `notification,all`.

```
$roleName = implode(' ,',$roleName); // "super-market" or "all"

        foreach ($roles->pluck('name')->toArray() as $roleName) {
            $user->removeRole($roleName); 
        }
```

Now what i need is irrespective of the role(any role) i want to delete that role ,some of the roles it's deleteing and remove the instance of the model from the `model_has_roles` and some of the roles are not deleted (for example all,notification),please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

there is no built-in laravel package for managing roles and permission and `removeRole()` is not in laravel (I dont know why you did wrote removeRole laravel method ), there is a package called [laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) that has the same table design of yours. if you are using this package you can find docs in [here](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/basic-usage). if you are writing your own try debugging it with `dd()` and tinker to find out what's wrong with some that they won't be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

I got it reverse in first place, you must use explode instead, and move first line into foreach loop

```
    foreach ($roles->pluck('name')->toArray() as $roleName) {
        $roleName = explode(',',$roleName); 
        $user->removeRole($roleName); 
    }
```

Comment: all -->one role name.notification-->another role name.